# Pyomo: using a list for parametrising a constraint

Tags: python, list, constraints, pyomo

I am trying to declare a constraint in Pyomo where one parameter would be a list instead of a scalar and then build the constraint by providing a set of the right dimension but it seems that Pyomo does the Cartesian product of every set and deduces the number of inputs (which are then considered as scalars).

Below a dummy example of what I want to achieve:

```
model.inputs = RangeSet(0,1)
model.x = model.inputs*model.inputs

model.p = Var()

def constraint_rule(model,x,i):
     return x[i] > model.p

model.constraint = Constraint(model.x,model.inputs,rule=constraint_rule)
```

To be more precise on what I want to achieve. My constraint is of the form:

```
f(x_0,x_1,i) > p
```

And  I'd like to input x as a vector instead of inputting separately x_0 and x_1 (or more if I have more x_i). So I want to input a list of lists for the first parameter and a iterator as the second parameter which could specify which element of the list I want.

I can of course decompose the list *x* of lenght n with n scalars *x[i]* but because I want to keep changing the size of the inputs, I wanted to only change *model.x* and hope it would automatically scale.

---

Below the full mathematical problem (I don't have enough reputation to put an image, sorry about that):

```
Tr(MixiNx) > p
```

Tr(N<sub>x</sub>) = 1

M<sup>i</sup><sub>0</sub> + M<sup>i</sup><sub>1</sub> = Id

M<sup>i</sup><sub>0</sub>, M<sup>i</sup><sub>1</sub> and N<sub>x</sub> SDP

Here the `M`s and `N`s are 2x2 matrices.
We have 4 `N` for bitstrings of lenght 2 and 2 matrices `M` per value of `i` (then x<sub>i</sub> is either 0 or 1).

Also `x` specifies the bitstring (here we have only x_0 and x_1) and `i` specifies which bit (for instance for i=0, we want the value x_0 ie the first bit of x). But `i` could be larger than the number of the number of bits in x (for instance we could set that for i=2, we want the value x_0 xor x_1 ie the parity of the bits). So I wanted to encode the 1sr constraint such it receives a bitstring `x` and a value `i` which could specify which information I want about that bitstring.

I hope that's clearer.

Comment: First, in your code you only seem to define two sets, one variable and one constraint - so there is no parameter that would be a "list" instead of a scalar. `model.x` in your code is now a set that is basically the cross product of `model.inputs` with itself (that is essentially what the `*` operator does when used with Pyomo sets). Therefore, please edit your question to clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: So to me ```model.x``` should be composed by 4 lists [0,0], [0,1], [1,0] and [1,1] (the cross product of ```model.inputs``` indeed). Is that not so?

Comment: Yes, what you say about `model.x` is correct. In your model, `model.p` is a scalar variable. So how would the constraint `model.p < [0,0]` work? Can you write your constraint in a mathematical form i.e. not in Pyomo syntax? Then I might be able to be of more help.

Comment: I edited the post. In short I'd like to have a list L of lists l[k] as a first parameter and an iterator as a second parameter that could specify which element I want in the list l[k].

Comment: I am afraid I still do not fully understand what you want to do. I believe you also might be confusing Python and Pyomo syntax. `model.x` is a set, which is usually used to index model parameters and variables. In your case, you use it as a value in a constraint. Do you want `model.x` to be a Pyomo Parameter instead and indexed per `model.inputs`?

Comment: That's very plausible since I started using pyomo recently. I still want ```model.x``` to index a model parameter but because of my constraint I'd like ```model.x``` to be somehow indexed by ```model.inputs``` before indexing my variable. When I pass ```model.x``` as a parameter of my constraint, I'd like to access model.x[0] and model.x[1]. Should I set ```model.x``` as a pyomo paramter?

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could specify your constraints as mathematical equations, and write some example data. Even in the updated version, I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Argh I am really sorry. I will write the full mathematical problem then. But I cannot post images because I don't have enough reputation. So I'll give it as a link.

Comment: That image link is really unreadable. The URL shortener is also a bit of a problem; you should not expect people to voluntarily click through to $dmr-knows-where.

Comment: I can read it perfectly. 
Sure but otherwise it's 5 lines long. I don't have of to have a latex rendering otherwise. I can try to write it directly here but it's will be hard to read. I am not sure it's better with the full link.